# JDBC in Web Service Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jdbc, glassfish

I have made an application with the java JDBC driver for MYSQL and that works fine. But now I'm trying to implement a web service into my application and I can't seem to get a connection made. Do I need to use a different driver or different way to connect to the MySQL server?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on the "can't seem" bit.

Comment: I've used the code from my Java Desktop app and have defined the JDBC driver but the web service returns false every time when using the code.

Comment: What does the log say?  "false" return isn't indicative of what's going on.

Comment: This is the return of the web service when under testing: http://i56.tinypic.com/rwuec1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the JDBC driver JAR either in a /lib directory that's visible to Glassfish (if it's shared) or in the WEB-INF/lib of your web service WAR.

You don't say what the error was.  If it's a ClassNotFoundException, it means the class loader couldn't find the JDBC driver JAR.

If the error message is "no suitable driver found", it usually means that the syntax of your connection URL isn't correct for the given driver.  The good news in that case is that the driver .class was picked up by the class loader.

Were you going to create a connection with a DriverManager, like you probably did with your app, or were you going to be ambitious and try to set up a connection pool?

Comment: Thanks, putting the driver in the /lib directory did give me something, but now I'm receiving a "Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server." error. and atm I don't think I should be ambitious with trying out pools.

Comment: The easiest way is setting up the connection pool and letting GlassFish handle that part for you.

Comment: Would you know any quick code to get the connection pool sorted?

Comment: I found the problem to be that netbeans couldn't make a connection to MySQL because something in the Mac OS was refusing the connection. Went to Ubuntu to do my coding, everything is working fine so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same driver. Most likely you don't have your connection pool in Glassfish properly set up.

You can read about it here http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7692/ablih?l=en&a=view

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. I tried the commands in asadmin, but couldn't get it to work or understand it fully.

Comment: Use the admin console... while you're still learning it's easier than the command line.